# how to programmatically create an imageView with id and src parameters?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-framelayout

The following works, but I want to eliminate the xml so that I can change the image programmatically:
Java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.p6_touch);
    ImageView floatImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.p6_imageView);
    floatImage.setOnTouchListener(this);    
}
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_black" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/p6_imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/p6_trail_map" >
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:onClick="showFlashlight"
          android:src="@drawable/legend_block24" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

In the documentation there is a [table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#lattrs) that maps XML to Java.

- For instance: `android:src` is equivalent to `setImageResource()`.

You will need to check the [inherited table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#inhattrs) for attributes from any super class.

- For instance: `android:id` is equivalent to `setId()`.

`width`, `height`, and `gravity` are all set in a LayoutParams object and passed to `setLayoutParams()`.

Understand that not every XML attribute has a matching Java method (and vica versa), but all of the attributes you are using do.

---

An Example, let's call this file `activity_main.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_black" >
    <!-- We'll add this missing ImageView back in with Java -->
    <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:onClick="showFlashlight"
          android:src="@drawable/legend_block24" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Now in our Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Let's create the missing ImageView
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

    // Now the layout parameters, these are a little tricky at first
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.p6_trail_map);
    image.setOnTouchListener(this);    

    // Let's get the root layout and add our ImageView
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
    layout.addView(image, 0, params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments.  I new enough that I don't know where in the Java code to put something line setImageSource().  If I want to change the image from p6_trail_map to p7_trail_map, do I set the image in the Java and then delete the XML src= statement?  If so, what happens to the second image?

Comment: I added an example of how to create a View in Java.

Comment: Thanks again, Sam.  I have to be out of town for a few weeks, but when I return I'll try this....really appreciate the example. I never would have put this together from the API's etc.  Jim